# Vector of Pointers, syntax for pushing element

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

```
vector<thread>* myVector;
```

Is what I used to declare a vector of thread pointers.

```
thread* new_thread = new thread(chef_thread,&kill, new std::mutex, &foodQ,     
    numberChefs); //New Thread
myVector->push_back(*new_thread);
```

Chef_Thread is a function that I made that's declared above in the same .cpp file.

I try compiling the code and everything goes to hell.
Thanks!

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Run-time errors or crashes? Unexpected results? Something else? Please elaborate! Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is error you got ? "Everything goes to hell" is not helping !

Comment: On a (possibly) unrelated note, do you come from Java or C# or another language where one need to use `new` to create objects? Because it's not needed in C++. In fact, if you do not `delete new_thread` after you push it into the vector you will have a memory leak. At least as the code is now.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<thread>* myVector;` declares a pointer to a `vector` of `thread`s.

The type you're looking for is `vector<thread*>`, which declares a `vector` of `thread` pointers.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a vector of smart pointers, e.g. `vector<unique_ptr<thread>>`

Answer (score 1):

user2899162 is correct in pointing out the immediate error in your code. However I doubt there is any need to use pointers at all.

As a general rule: You should not have raw – i.e. manually typed – `new` and `delete` in your program. Because that is manual resource management and you *will* get it wrong. Use [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) instead, i.e. rely on constructors and automatic execution of destructors at the end of an object’s scope to avoid manual resource management. [1]

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.push_back(std::thread(
        chef_thread,
        &kill,
        std::mutex(), // this is weird, see below
        &foodQ,     
        numberChefs));
```

All thread and mutex objects as well as the vector itself will be destroyed automatically as soon as `threads` goes out of scope.

Now for the weirdness: the standalone mutex (the `new std::mutex` argument in your code). That creates a mutex object that is only known to the `chef_thread` function. We’d need more code to say anything definitive, but I smell an error here. A mutex is a sync machanism for a shared resource. Everyone accessing the resource *must* do so via the same mutex. But how can that be possible if only the one function knows about the mutex? The only way I see is passing along a reference or pointer to the mutex from inside `chef_thread`, which is a red flag itself.

[1] There are, of course, exceptions to this rule. The obvious one is a wrapper/container class that has `new` in its constructor and the corresponding `delete` in its destructor. In a nutshell that’s how you implement RAII and that’s how all `std` containers, smart pointers and other resource wrappers work.